# A better way to write jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, performance, function, optimization

This is the function which I wrote and currently using in my project But I want to make sure if there is a better way to write it:

```
function pageLoader(pageIndex) {

    $(".ServicesSectionWrapper,.ServicesSectionWrapper .Selector,.ServicesSection,.JournalSectionWrapper,.JournalSectionWrapper .Selector,.JournalSection,.AboutSectionWrapper,.AboutSectionWrapper .Selector,.AboutSection").hide();

    switch (pageIndex) {

    case 1:
        $(".AboutSectionWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
            $("#AboutWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
                $("#ManagerWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
                    $("#DeveloperWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
                        $("#DesignerWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
                            $(".AboutSection").fadeIn(400, function () {
                                $(".AboutSection").addClass("PreLoadRotate")
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        });
        break;

    case 2:
        $(".JournalSectionWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
            $("#DateOne").fadeIn(400, function () {
                $("#DateTwo").fadeIn(400, function () {
                    $("#DateThree").fadeIn(400, function () {
                        $("#DateFour").fadeIn(400, function () {
                            $("#DateFive").fadeIn(400, function () {
                                $("#DateSix").fadeIn(400, function () {
                                    $("#DateSeven").fadeIn(400, function () {
                                        $("#DateEight").fadeIn(400, function () {
                                            $(".JournalSection").fadeIn(400, function () {
                                                $(".JournalSection").addClass("PreLoadRotate")
                                            })
                                        })
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        });
        break;

    case 3:
        $(".ServicesSectionWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
            $("#AppsWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
                $("#ResponsiveWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
                    $("#DigitalWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
                        $("#PTRWrapper").fadeIn(400, function () {
                            $(".ServicesSection").fadeIn(400, function () {
                                $(".ServicesSection").addClass("PreLoadRotate")
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        });
        break;

    }
}
```

And Here is The HTML:

```
    <div class="AboutSectionWrapper">

        <div class="Selector" id="AboutWrapper"></div>
        <div class="Selector" id="DesignerWrapper"></div>
        <div class="Selector" id="ManagerWrapper"></div>
        <div class="Selector" id="DeveloperWrapper"></div>

    <div class="AboutSection">
        <div class="Indicator"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

This is a menu (AboutSectionWrapper) which has selectors as you can see and I want to load the menu first and then sequentially load the selectors and finally fade in the Menu indicator and add a CSS class which has a Transition in it.

It is the same for other Cases but for example in CASE 2 There are more Selectors!

Please advice, thank you.

Comment: Try codereview.stackexchange.com too.

Comment: Thank you Marco I just did that.

Comment: I'm panicking just to see this.

Comment: @EricHerlitz That's the point my friend I am  sequentially fading in elements and that's all, There are just some Div elements in the HTML with those ID and Classes and that is why I didn't post the HTML part.

Comment: You are in callback hell mate, really bad. Even if it becomes a bit more code you should separate this for maintainability.

Comment: @EricHerlitz What do you exactly mean? How should I do this?

Comment: @DavidThomas I already described that!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about revising/improving code (that apparently works?) rather than solving a coding problem. Also the OP appears unwilling to clarify the question or provide relevant, necessary HTML upon which the jQuery/JavaScript is apparently supposed to work.

Comment: @DavidThomas Look at the question again instead of posting irrelevant comments!!!

Comment: And this is why people are retracting from answering questions from new users, four good answers and not a single comment on these from the author.

Comment: @EricHerlitz No my friend I am testing the answers and when I am done I will comment on every answer !

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions... but...

The logic of the code seems to be to fade in an element, then to fade in a child (or sibling?) Although as the intial selector is a class, but the subsequent ones id's I am not sure.

I would use a class identifier rather than ID. And combine this with child or nextSibling to call the fade in a recursive function.

So (typed in right here, not tested) something like...

```
case n:
    fadein(<rootselector>)
case m:
```

...

```
function fadein(selector)  {
    $(selector).fadeIn(400, function () {
        if ($(selector).nextSibling(<classselector>)) {
            fadein($selector.nextSibling(<classselector>);
}   }   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, I would have done something like:

```
$('.date').each(function(i){
    $(this).fadeIn(400*i);
});
```

Do you see where I'm going with this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in so many ways.  This is a 1:am solution, pretty straight forward and it can be refined and improved but you will get the idea!

```
// Construct an object structure with your chains instead
var elementAnimation = [{
    "element": ".AboutSectionWrapper",
    "effect": "fadeIn",
    "duration": 400
},{
    "element": "#AboutWrapper",
    "effect": "fadeIn",
    "duration": 400
},{
    "element": ".AboutSection",
    "effect": "addClass",
    "className": "PreLoadRotate"
}]

// Simple but effective callback handler
function MyCallback(index){

    if(elementAnimation.length <= index) return;
    var obj = elementAnimation[index];
    index++;

    if(obj.effect == "fadeIn") {
        $(obj.element).fadeIn(400, MyCallback(index))
    }

    if(obj.effect == "addClass") {
        $(obj.element).addClass(obj.className);
        MyCallback(index); // If necessary
    }
}

// Start
MyCallback(0);
```

You can implement some more intel in the json, pretty simple huh :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's probably what I would do:

```
function runFades(selectors, i) {
    i = i || 0;
    $(selectors[i]).fadeIn(400, function() {
        if (i < selectors.length) {
            runFades(selectors, i+1);
        }
        else {
            $(selectors[i-1]).addClass("PreLoadRotate");
        }
    });
}
```

And then run it in your `case` statements:

```
switch (pageIndex) {
    case 1:
        runFades(['.AboutSectionWrapper', '#AboutWrapper', ... ]);
        break;
    ...
}
```